# iOS: How to share documents between iPad & iPhone versions of app?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ios-universal-app

I was under the impression that when Apple rolled out universal apps, that a sharing mechanism was provided to sync files between the same app installed on more than one device. However I don't see much evidence of this. What am I missing?

(Note I would prefer to avoid iCloud, because of privacy concerns about Apple giving users' data to the govt since that is a legal gray area etc.)

Comment: do you want to share documents with other devices?

Comment: That's what iCloud is for. If this privacy concern really effects your users, you could simply prompt them asking wether or not they wish to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a cloud service, such as iCloud to store your shared data.  There is no sharing mechanism with a Universal App to share data between devices.  The Universal App just lets the same App work on both iPad and iPhone.  This is a nice bonus to the customer, because if they have both devices, they only pay for the App once.

The App will need to go get the data from the users storage.  If you don't want to use iCloud, you can develop your own, by using storage services from Amazon Web Services, or Microsoft Windows Azure, however, you are stuck with paying for the bandwidth and storage on those services.  You're also getting yourself into more work as you'll have to come up with the server side support, and web services yourself.   Plus, on the mobile device, you'll need to concern yourself with handling losing a network connection, caching the data on the device, and then sending it when connectivity is regained.

Comment: iCould is insecure. Why let the American equivalent of the Stasi or KGB have access to my users' data??

Comment: I understand your concern with governments having access to data.  That also did not have to do with the original question.  I am not sure you will find any cloud based system that won't have this issue, unless you build it yourself.  The fact still remains that my answer is correct in regards to "sharing information on a universal app".  I don't understand why this was initially accepted and just now marked as "unaccepted".